# RabbitMQ multiple listeners for same message prevent duplicate listening

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am using rabbitmq in spring boot application. I am using aws ecs for deployment. Now suppose multiple instance is running of my service. and rabbitmq listening for order create is registered with direct exchange.. So what happen when order is placed? will my both the instance of service will get same message? If yes, How to prevent duplicate message on those 2 listeners?

Comment: Have you looked into clustering?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger   You mean logs?

Comment: No, clustering the RabbitMQ servers with a load balancer.

Comment: Is your service will create listeners for same queue on direct exchange? Direct exchange will not deliver message to all consumers on same queue it follows round-robin.

Comment: Yes, service will create listeners on same queue.. From logs I can see its distributed across listeners.. no duplicate message.. So this is correct behavior, right?

Comment: @MihirShah Yes that is correct behavior.

Comment: This question is very poorly-formulated. Would you be able to supply a code example and a more specific question? I could offer some insight, but I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: @theMayer Got answer already for my question. Sorry for not explaining in a way you can understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the service creates multiple Listeners/Consumers for same queue on a direct exchange below mechanism is applicable:

**By default, RabbitMQ will send each message to the next consumer, in sequence. On average every consumer will get the same number of messages. This way of distributing messages is called round-robin.**

Best Tutorial for this topic: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. Can you comment on my another query at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333616/ecs-multiple-tasks-of-same-service-behaviour-for-scheduler

Comment: If your question is cleared, Please accept the answer. Thanks. Your other question is out of my knowledge scope.