# ECS multiple tasks of same service behaviour for scheduler

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have spring boot application. Multiple Fargate tasks of same service is running. Now I have scheduler performed in service. So is scheduler will be performed twice as 2 tasks are running? How it behaves?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If the tasks are the same, and you expect each task to execute some work on a schedule, both will run the scheduled work.